# Saving an activity state when I press up button in action bar

Tags: android

I'm developing an android Wallpaper app consists of 2 activity, main activity displays the images from the internet in ListView and the second activity displays the preview of that image. 
my problem is when I press the back button in preview activity to go back to the main activity, the main activity displays the images from the beginning and I would like to display the images from the last I clicked on.

The following code in onCreate() method in Main Activity:

```
    // Find a reference to the {@link ListView} in the layout
    ListView gameListView = findViewById(R.id.list);


    mEmptyStateTextView = findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
    gameListView.setEmptyView(mEmptyStateTextView);

    // Create a new adapter that takes an empty list of games as input
    mAdapter = new GamesAdapter(this, new ArrayList<Games>());

    // Set the adapter on the {@link ListView}
    // so the list can be populated in the user interface
    gameListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // Set an item click listener on the ListView, which sends an intent to a web browser
    // to open a website with more information about the selected game.
    gameListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {


            // Find the current game that was clicked on
            Games currentGame = mAdapter.getItem(position);


            // Convert the String URL into a URI object (to pass into the Intent constructor)
            Uri gameUri = Uri.parse(currentGame.getUrl());
            String name = currentGame.getName();

            // Create a new intent to view the game URI
            Intent i = new Intent(GamesActivity.this, PreviewActivity.class);
            i.setData(gameUri);
            i.putExtra("name", name);
            startActivity(i);


        }
    });
```

The following code in onCreate() method in Preview Activity:

```
    final Uri i = getIntent().getData();
    String profile = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
    photographer.setText(profile);

    Picasso.with(this).load(i).into(img);

    saveImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            downloadFile(i);
        }
    });
```

Comment: you need to keep your activity in stack. by this you will be restored the activity in previous state

Comment: How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

I think what your are looking for is the method `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` here you can save your values in the outState and get them in `onCreate()` at the `savedInstanceState`

[here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#java) is a very good example how to use it.

Comment: I don't need to save values, I want to save the whole activity layout state in the ListView

Comment: i think you have to set the position manually again with the savedInstanceState

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to preserve the scroll distance. For that what you need to do is you can preserve using `Bundle` object. But you can also clear current activity then you will get the same results.

Add this outside the `onCreate()` method(this is [java](/questions/tagged/java)):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    this.finish(); //important
}
```

`finish()` clears activity from back stack.

Comment: Nothing happens.

Comment: What do you actually want to do? Do you need to preserve the scroll or something else?

Comment: Yes, I want to preserve the scroll when I press the back button.

Comment: Where did you place this code? It should be out side the onCreate()

Comment: I putted the code outside on Create() method in Preview Activity, That's right or not ?

Comment: If you are clicking the toolbar button then there is different code for that. If you click the back button on the phone I think this should work.

Comment: I pressed the back button on the phone.

Comment: What actually happens? Does the activity close?

Comment: No, it displays the photo from the beginning.